# Map array of objects to Dict with key as Enum

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, dictionary

I got a dict of enum as key and values as object

```
 @Published var subscriptionProducts = [SubscriptionType: SKProduct]()

enum SubscriptionType {
        case monthly = "uniqueID"
        case annualy = "uniqueID"
    }
```

I got another array of type *SKProduct*
I want to assign it to my dict with a property of each object as key, and the object itself as value

Trying

```
 subscriptionProducts = Dictionary(uniqueKeysWithValues:products.map({$0.productIdentifier , $0 }))
```

But I got
*Type of expression is ambiguous without more context*

the *productIdentifier* is of type String, how to assign it to the rawValue of my enum?

The result I want to achieve later is to get the specific object using that key

```
   let monthlySubscriptionProduct = subscriptionProducts[.monthly]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to first declare your `SubscriptionType` enumeration `RawValue` as `String`. Then you will need to convert your `productIdentifier` String value to `SubscriptionType` using its fallible `init(rawValue:)` initializer. Something like:

```
enum SubscriptionType: String {
    case monthly, annualy
}
```

---

```
let subscriptionProducts: [SubscriptionType: SKProduct] = Dictionary(uniqueKeysWithValues: products.compactMap {
    guard let subscriptionType = SubscriptionType(rawValue: $0.productIdentifier) else {
        return nil
    }
    return (subscriptionType, $0)
})
let monthlySubscriptionProduct = subscriptionProducts[.monthly]
```

---

But IMO that's not what you really want. Looks like what you are trying to accomplish is to group all monthly subscriptions which can be done using reduce as follow:

```
let subscriptionProducts: [SubscriptionType: [SKProduct]] = products.reduce(into: [:]) {
    guard let subscriptionType = SubscriptionType(rawValue: $1.productIdentifier) else {
        return
    }
    $0[subscriptionType, default: []].append($1)
}

let monthlySubscriptions = subscriptionProducts[.monthly] ?? []
```

Comment: Thanks! yes you noticed, as for now I got only one of each type, but later I will have multiples of each type, I will use your second solution also. too bad I can't give you +2 haha